# My empty object is not recognised by my project as moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my code I am making a flying object, shoot bullets. The rigidbody is connected to a bullet 3d object and the Cube variable is connected to an empty game object. The problem with the code is the bullets are spawned at the position of the cube at the very start position.(0,0,0) not the current position of the "flying object". This is all with Unity C# by the way. I have looked up this question a few times but most suggestions are changes of code that don't work or needing more information in terms of what each thing is connected to. The script is connected to the flying object. Sorry for the bad variable names. The code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


    public class SHooting : MonoBehaviour {
    public Rigidbody Sphere;
    public Transform Cube;

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            Rigidbody a;

            a = Instantiate(Sphere, Cube.forward, Cube.rotation) as Rigidbody;
            a.AddForce(Cube.forward * 200);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use overloaded `Instantiate(...)` method which takes parameter for position.

Comment: @m.rogalski he's already using it, the only problem is that he's using a directional vector `Cube.forward` in that place.

Comment: @Iggy Okay sorry, my bad. Just figured out his mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're setting the position to `Cube.forward` which will probably be equal to something like `Vector3(0,1,0);`

What you want to do instead is take the position of the Cube by using `Cube.transform.position`

so your instantiate would look like this:

`a = Instantiate(Sphere, Cube.transform.position, Cube.rotation) as Rigidbody;`

Comment: You said he should use `Cube.transform.position` but you're using `Cube.forward` instead. :)

Comment: @WilliamPeterswald Good to hear, could you accept the answer to indicate this helped you solve your problem